# No jobs functions found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I am trying to make scheduled mail with azure functions on Visual Studio but this time I took No Jobs functions found error. How can I fix and send this mails?
Also I made this function on Azure Portal and it works. I'm trying to convert Visual Studio.

```
using System;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;


namespace FifteenMinMail
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            config.UseTimers();
            JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
    }
    public class ScheduledMail
    {

        public static Mail Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
            JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            config.UseTimers();
            JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
            var today = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
            log.Info($"Generating daily report for {today} at {DateTime.Now}");

            Mail message = new Mail()
            {
                Subject = "15 DK'LIK TEST MAILI"
            };

            Content content = new Content
            {
                Type = "text/plain",
                Value = "Bu mail 15 dk da bir yinelenecektir."
            };

            message.AddContent(content);
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Error; https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcERt.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing up web jobs and azure functions.
those are different but related technologys. 
have a look at this if you want to create an azure function in visual studio:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio